# Cloud CDNの署名付きURLにおけるキャッシュの挙動について

Tags: google-cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Cloud CDNの署名付きURLにおいて、署名部分が変わってもキャッシュURLが同一の場合にCDNでキャッシュを返すように設定することは可能でしょうか？

Google CloudのCloud CDNにおいて、署名付きURLを使用してキャッシュしたコンテンツにアクセスさせようとしています。オリジンはCloud Storageの非公開バケットです。

この時、アクセスの都度新しい署名付きURLを生成(キャッシュURLは同一)してアクセスすると全てのリクエストのレスポンスコードが200になり、毎回オリジンでコンテンツ取得しているように見えるのですが、キャッシュURLが同一ならCDNがキャッシュを返すようにするように設定することは可能でしょうか。

Cloud CDNの仕様について調査中なのですが、上記についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 以下のように回答をいただきましたのでこの質問をクローズします。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159101/the-behavior-of-caching-in-signed-urls-for-cloud-cdn